# ArtifactTransferException in Eclipse project when importing the Examples

Tags: netty

I'm trying to run some of the Netty example projects. After importing the Maven project, Eclipse reports the following problem:

```
ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact io.netty:netty-tcnative:jar:${os.detected.classifier}:1.1.33.Fork2 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Illegal character in path at index 96: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-tcnative/1.1.33.Fork2/netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork2-${os.detected.classifier}.jar
```

Things I've tried after researching related questions:

- Deleting the lastupdated files (seems to be a common cause of ArtifactTransferExceptions)
- Manually adding the os-maven-plugin to the eclipse plugins folder [as described here](http://ArtifactTransferException:%20Could%20not%20transfer%20artifact%20io.netty:netty-tcnative:jar:$%7Bos.detected.classifier%7D:1.1.33.Fork2%20from/to%20central%20(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2):%20Illegal%20character%20in%20path%20at%20index%2096:%20http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-tcnative/1.1.33.Fork2/netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork2-$%7Bos.detected.classifier%7D.jar)
- Cleaning the project
- Deleting the eclipse project and re-importing

What should I try next (or am I even going down the right path for running the Netty examples)?

Comment: Incidentally, I can build the package using "mvn package" from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. It was solved by adding:

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

inside the  tag. Questions see here: https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with the os-maven-plugin and your eclipse installation. The solution is to manually add the os-maven-plugin to the eclipse plugins folder. In your question you wrote that you have done this. However, in your case I think that eclipse is still not able to run the os-maven-plugin. Therefore, I suggest to try again to move the os-maven-plugin to the eclipse plugins folder.

In the problem report of eclipse you can find the property `${os.detected.classifier}`. Eclipse can not transfer the artifact as this property is not evaluated. If you run mvn package the property is evaluated. Therefore, with mvn package the transfer and the build is successful.

The property `${os.detected.classifier}` belongs to the [os-maven-plugin](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin) that allows to use platform-dependent project propertes. Eclipse does not evaluate these expressions. According to the [readme of the plugin](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin#issues-with-eclipse-m2e-or-other-ides) you have to download the plugin as jar and put it into the `<ECLIPSE_HOME>/plugins` directory. In my case with the jar in my eclipse plugins directory I was able to successfully execute the pom file in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

After manually adding the plugin to the plugins folder, adding this to the pom under < plugins > ... < /plugins> fixed the issue for me.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

You can also right click on the pom.xml file from the Package Explorer -> Maven -> Add Plugin -> specify group ID and artifact ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

then it would print the message at the begining

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: linux
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: linux-x86_64
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
```

then stop the mvn command, as you already get the properties right value, stop the command or you can't find the message in too much printing, then add the following in the pom.xml file of parent project:

```
<properties>
    <os.detected.name>linux</os.detected.name>
    <os.detected.arch>x86_64</os.detected.arch>
    <os.detected.classifier>linux-x86_64</os.detected.classifier>
...
```